# Reading whitespace and linespace delimited complex numbers from a text file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, textscan

I have four streams of complex numbers in four columns of a [text file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3K3K2U7YVGxN0FXcW52Sm9MVGM/view?usp=sharing)

I have to read them into a MATLAB matrix in the same format.

I tried the following, but it does not work

```
fid =  fopen('~/<path-to-file>/<fileName>.txt','r');
out = textscan(fid, '(%f,%f) \b\t(%f,%f) \b\t(%f,%f) \b\t(%f,%f) \n','CollectOutput',1);
tapWeights = [out{1} + 1i*out{2} out{3} + 1i*out{4} out{5} + 1i*out{6} out{7} + 1i*out{8}];
fclose(fid);
```

Note that help options for `textscan` lists `\b\t` as the white space delimiter.

The following is the output I get,

```
>> out

out = 

    [1x8 double]

>> out{1}

ans =

     1     0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: try `dlmread` - you can set the delimiter you wish to use.

Comment: You don't even need to specify the whitespace in your format string – `textscan(fid, '(%f,%f) (%f,%f) (%f,%f) ')` is sufficient. You might also consider using the `'CollectOutput'` option.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. The extra (%f,%f) is a typo, but that is not the issue. Can you elaborate on the 'CollectOutput'? A full answer with working code would be very helpful.

Comment: If `textscan(fid, '(%f,%f) (%f,%f) (%f,%f) ')` doesn't work for you then your data is not what you claim. There may be other characters or maybe you don't have new lines. Hard to say much without the real file (or an example one that exhibit the same issue). Read the documentation for `'CollectOutput'` and try it once you get the rest working to see if it's something you want.

Comment: I've tried all that and it doesn't work. You can copy the numbers given above into a text file to verify if it works. See my edit.

Comment: FWIW, I tried @horchler s solution, and it works if the input text file has exactly the same format as specified. The way it is typed in the question, all the numbers are in one line, and that's not the same as your description. Maybe this is why it isn't working?

Comment: @Naveen: I did exactly that and my `textscan` worked fine. As I said, is t'd to say much more without the real file (or an example one that exhibit the same issue). Copy-pasting changes many things. I suggest that you provide a link to an example file.

Comment: @horchler: Yes, I just noticed that there is a problem copying input in highlighted text to a txt file. Sorry for the trouble. I have added the entire file in the edit. Please note that the text file has 4 columns of complex numbers now.

Comment: Be very careful: mixing space-delimited arrays and complex numbers can be dangerous: `[3 + 2i]` *could* be `[3, +2i]` as well. I suggest using a comma between array elements to make your intentions clear to the user.

Comment: @Naveen: I just downloaded your file and ran your code (only changed path and removed `'CollectOutput'` because the `tapWeights` wasn't updated). It worked perfectly fine in R2015b on OS X. So did `textscan(fid, '(%f,%f) (%f,%f) (%f,%f) (%f,%f) ')`.

Comment: @AndrasDeak: I'm not sure what you're talking about. The only thing in the file are doubles, which are then assembled into complex values after they're loaded in Matlab. If you're referring to the line after `textscan`, that seems to be valid Matlab code, though I would remove the spaces around `+` just for clarity.

Comment: @Naveen: The only whitespace characters in your file are spaces. There don't seem to be any `'\b'` (backspace) or `'\t'` (tab) characters, so adding those to your format string is unnecessary and may be confusing `textscan` if you're using an old version of Matlab.

Comment: @horchler the latter is exactly what I meant.

Comment: @horchler This is strange indeed. I have R2015a on Linux Ubuntu based OS and both the formats of textscan(..) discussed above does not work for me. out{2} to out{8} or out(2) to out(8),whichever applies, are always empty or NaN.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I missed something, a simple [`regexp`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html), [`str2double`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html), [`cellfun`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) and [`reshape`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) does the trick (assuming that the structure of the matrix is known in order to reshape it.

```
s='(1.00000000,0.00000000) (1.00000000,0.00000000) (-0.00000004,1.00000000) (-0.00000004,-1.00000000) (0.66912299,0.74315202) (0.66912299,0.74315202) (-0.74315202,0.66912293) (0.74315202,-0.66912305) (-0.10454900,0.99452001) (-0.10454900,0.99452001) (-0.99452001,-0.10454904) (0.99452001,0.10454895) (-0.80903500,0.58776098) (-0.80903500,0.58776098) (-0.58776093,-0.80903500) (0.58776104,0.80903500) (-0.97813898,-0.20795099) (-0.97813898,-0.20795099) (0.20795104,-0.97813898) (-0.20795095,0.97813898) (-0.49995700,-0.86605000) (-0.49995700,-0.86605000) (0.86605000,-0.49995697) (-0.86605000,0.49995703) (0.30907401,-0.95103800) (0.30907401,-0.95103800) (0.95103800,0.30907404) (-0.95103800,-0.30907398) (0.91357303,-0.40667400) (0.91357303,-0.40667400) (0.40667397,0.91357303) (-0.40667403,-0.91357303) (0.30893400,0.95108300)';
a=reshape(cellfun(@(x) str2double(x{1})+str2double(x{2})*1j,regexp(s,'[(]([^,]*),([^)]*)[)]','tokens')),3,[])'
```

Comment: Yes, you're missing something important – as the OP says in the question the data comes from a text file, not a generic string. Also, `regexp` is much slower than `textscan` and `str2double` is a better choice than `str2num` (see documentation).

Comment: @horchler. You are right about str2double, corrected that. regexp may be slower, but I prefer it due to it's flexibility as long as performance does not matter.

Comment: "a simple `regexp`, `str2double`, `cellfun` and `reshape` does the trick`": for an appropriately chosen meaning of "simple";)

Comment: Unless my eyes are fooling me, that (at least to me) string of commands isn't perceived as "simple".